# Getting 504 Error on all S3 calls from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In the last couple hours my app started giving this error whenever I try to upload something to S3.

> Unable to unmarshall error response (Unable to parse JSON String.).
> Response Code: 504, Response Text: Gateway Time-out, Response Headers:
> {X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1, Server=awselb/2.0,
> Connection=keep-alive, X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 504,
> X-Android-Sent-Millis=1606318289732, Content-Length=132,
> X-Android-Received-Millis=1606318300066, Date=Wed, 25 Nov 2020
> 15:31:41 GMT, Content-Type=text/html}

We are using this to instantiante and upload our files:

```
sTransferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                                .context(mActivity)
                                .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                                .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(sCredProvider, Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)))
                                .build();

...

TransferObserver observer = sTransferUtility.upload(MY_BUCKET, mPictureFile.getName(), mPictureFile);
...

observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                            if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                                ...
                            } else if (state == TransferState.CANCELED || state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                                ...
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                            //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR RETURNS
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Always check https://status.aws.amazon.com/ - it seems like there are some issues with multiple services in us-east-1 though S3 isn't mentioned specifically.

Comment: @stdunbar Ah, I checked about 15-20 mins before I posted here and everything was fine there. Maybe it is related. Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a major issue at AWS us-east-1 region.

> 9:52 AM PST: The Kinesis Data Streams API is currently impaired in the
> US-EAST-1 Region. As a result customers are not able to write or read
> data published to Kinesis streams. CloudWatch metrics and events are
> also affected, with elevated PutMetricData API error rates and some
> delayed metrics. While EC2 instances and connectivity remain healthy,
> some instances are experiencing delayed instance health metrics, but
> remain in a healthy state. AutoScaling is also experiencing delays in
> scaling times due to CloudWatch metric delays. The issue is also
> affecting other services, including ACM, Amplify Console, API Gateway,
> AppMesh, AppStream2, AppSync, Athena, Batch, CloudFormation,
> CloudTrail, Cognito, Connect, DynamoDB, EventBridge, Glue, IoT
> Services, Lambda, LEX, Managed Blockchain, Marketplace, Personalize,
> RDS, Resource Groups, SageMaker, Support Console, Well Architected,
> and Workspaces. For further details on each of these services, please
> see the Personal Health Dashboard. Other services, like S3, remain
> unaffected by this event. This issue has also affected our ability to
> post updates to the Service Health Dashboard. We are continuing to
> work towards resolution.

More info here: https://status.aws.amazon.com/